# Is it better to overload weights on pushups or bench press for healthy shoulders?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-gain, chest

Pushups are often recommended as a shoulder healthy alternative for training chest, so I am wondering is it better to overload weight for pushups once you can do 20+ perfect form normal pushups or is it better to switch to benchpress for chest gains?

Answer (score 2):

Neither are really great for your shoulders. In fact, some of the most wrecked shoulders I've seen are from people who bench press all day and neglect their back and deltoids (the front, top, and rear of which make up your shoulder muscles).

I would very much recommend using the [standing overhead press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BBMilitaryPress.html). For bodyweight, consider [dive bombers](http://www.livestrong.com/video/1008029-military-dive-bomber-body-weight-exercise/).